# Mongodb like statement with array

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, database, nosql

I am trying to save some db action by compiling a looped bit of code with a single query, Before I was simply adding to the the like statements using a loop before firing off the query but i cant get the same idea going in Mongo, id appreciate any ideas....
I am basically trying to do a like, but with the value as an array

('app', replaces 'mongodb' down to my CI setup )

Here's how I was doing it pre mongofication:

```
    foreach ($workids as $workid):
         $this->ci->app->or_like('work',$workid)    ;
    endforeach;
    $query = $this->ci->db->get("who_users");
    $results = $query->result();
    print_r($results);
```

and this is how I was hoping I could get it to work, but no joy here, that function is only designed to accept strings

```
    $query = $this->ci->app->like('work',$workids,'.',TRUE,TRUE)->get("who_users");
    print_r($query);
```

If anyone can think of a way any cunning methods I can get my returned array with a single call again it would be great I've not found any documentation on this sort of query, The only way i can think of is to loop over the query and push it into a new results array.... but that is really gonna hurt if my app scales up.

Comment: I wonder is it possible that I can do a where_in with wildcards somehow

Comment: What kind of query are you trying to run against MongoDB? I don't quite understand that from your question above.

Comment: well im checking if an id is in a field of listed ids so basically something like -  get rows where ids contain $id,
I am doing this now with 

         foreach ($workids as $workid):
   $html .=  "\r\n friendsbox[".$workid."] ='';";
   $this->ci->app->like('workids',$workid,'im',TRUE,TRUE);
  endforeach;
  
  $query = $this->ci->app->get("who_users");

But that only returns the last query i need a way to do it over an array really. , or more importantly a way to chain them I think.

Comment: also the variable would be something like 08478498657659 and the rows in the table have fields  i am searching through with the LIKE statement have contents like "90840974074,3988752852,2986387548764, 39868529864"

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [codeigniter-mongodb-library](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library)? Based on the existing [or_like()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) documentation, it looks like CI wraps each match with `%` wildcards. The equivalent query in Mongo would be a series of regex matches in an `$or` clause:

```
db.who_users.find({
    $or: [
    { work: /.*workIdA.*/ },
    { work: /.*workIdB.*/ },
    ...
]});
```

Unfortunately, this is going to be quite inefficient unless (1) the `work` field is indexed and (2) your regexes are anchored with some constant value (e.g. `/^workId.*/`). This is described in more detail in Mongo's [regex documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions).

Based on your comments to the OP, it looks like you're storing multiple ID's in the `work` field as a comma-delimited string. To take advantage of Mongo's schema, you should model this as an array of strings. Thereafter, when you query on the `work` field, Mongo will consider all values in the array (documented discussed [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ValueinanArray)).

```
db.who_users.find({
    work: "workIdA"
});
```

This query would match a record whose `work` value was `["workIdA", "workIdB"]`. And if we need to search for one of a set of ID's (taking this back to your OR query), we can extend this example with the [$in](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in) operator:

```
db.who_users.find({
    work: { $in: ["workIdA", "workIdB", ...] }
});
```

If that meets your needs, be sure to index the `work` field as well.

Comment: yes you are right, I have recently converted to the Code igniter MongoDB library, and that would be better structured in the new environment - Looks like I'll need to build a function in the library to try and deal with the mulitple clauses.

Comment: Are you sure a new method is necessary? I haven't worked with the library, but `where_in()` looks like what you'd need.